# Kinetics "Master Equation"

Tags: networks, algorithms, literature-search

In stochastic (probabilistic) models, the evolution of a system over time is calculated using a "Master Equation" which also factors the external and internal noise / perturbations in order to more accurately replicate the behavior of a biological system (e.g. cell growth). I am unable to understand what is it, specifically, about the "Master Equation" that allows computational biologists to replicate a biological network with noise?

The [Master Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_equation) is the phenominological description of a non-stationary (i.e., evolving with time) process.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Perhaps it would be easier to answer if you pointed towards a paper or a course book where you found this reference. I have never heard of this Master Equation (but maybe this is specific to a sub-field or something)

Comment: @mobs By "noise" here are you referring to the probabilistic change in state of individual members? Regarding perturbations, if you mean external perturbations then they're not always accounted for (they would need to be made explicit in the differential equations).